# How to use Invoke in c# 4.0 service class

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, windows-services, invoke

I have a winforms applications which is reading strings using sockets and the sockets are under backgroundWorker thread.

Things are working fine, but as per the new company standards my manager wants it to be run as service rather putting this winforms application in the startup folder always.

The problem is that we are using below line of code in this winforms application

```
Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
                  delegate { _logger.Error((String.Format("Error: {0}", _socketError))); }
                  ));
```

Can somebody guide what ca I do to use the above line of code in the windowserverice project

please suggest

Thanks

**Update**: I need to use invoke because this statement is running in the DoWork event of backgroundWorker component.

Comment: Does _logger.Error write to some sort of winform control?

Comment: no, it is logging to a log file. this is basciall a NLog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `_logger` is just writing to a log file, I do not understand the original intention behind using `Invoke` in the first place.  I think you will be safe replacing that line with:

```
_logger.Error(String.Format("Error: {0}", _socketError));
```

Comment: Shax, `Invoke` is not necessary unless you are performing cross-thread update of a UI control. Since you will be creating a windows service, **and** not updating any UI elements (you're only writing to a file), you do not need to wrap your call within  an `Invoke`

Comment: if I dont do invoke then it gives cross thread error because it is under backgroundworker process

Comment: Tung is right, but where is the error you're getting exactly, you should add some more details.

Comment: I'm very confused now.  You would only receive that exception if `_logger.Error` is modifying a UI element.  Is _logger a wrapper for NLog? What else is performed within `_logger.Error`? If it is a wrapper, could you please post the code?

Comment: Tung, you were right, I tried your suggestion and it worked. sorry my bad. Because in Winform application I was updating my UI and thats why I suspected the same code would be required in Windows Service. sorry friend. You WON !!!